# displaying image in react that is stored in my django backend

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django

I am currently facing a rather strange issue and was wondering if anyone would know the solution. I am making an api call to my Django backend to get details on profiles

```
export const ProfilesPage = () => {

    
    const classes = useStyles()
    useEffect(() => {
        getProfiles()
    })
    
    const [profiles, setProfiles] = useState([])

    let imgLink = ''

    let getProfiles = async () => {
        let response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/profiles', {
            method: "GET"
        })
        let data = await response.json()
        // console.log(data[0].profile_image)
        imgLink = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' + data[0].profile_image
        console.log(imgLink)
    }
        

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            ProfilesPage
            <img alt='profile' src={imgLink} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

the last line of my getProfiles function I am console.loging the image link. The link is appearing on my console and when i click on it, the correct image is being opened in my browser. I am unsure why react is not displaying the image when the link is clearly working. Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Try using state instead of `let img = ''`

Example:

```
const [img, setImg] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const getProfiles = async () => {
        let response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/profiles', {
            method: "GET"
        })
        let data = await response.json()
        // console.log(data[0].profile_image)
        imgLink = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' + data[0].profile_image
        setImg(imgLink)
    }
   getProfiles();
}, [profiles])
```

Then use the state in your return:

```
return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            ProfilesPage
            <img alt='profile' src={img} />
        </div>
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to store the image URL in `imgLink` it's being reset to empty string each time the component is re-rendered.

What you can try is storing the image URL in a state which will persist between each render.